# How to retrieve data from xhttp.send() in node.js express

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax

so I have this line in front page:

```js
var x = "Hi";
var y = 123;

xhttp.open("POST", "/toNodeServer", true);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

         
  
  xhttp.send(x, y);
```

and in the server I have the following:

```js
outer.post('/toNodeServer', function(req, res, next){
 
  var x = req.body


console.log(x);
```

so the result is it does not send y value, I got this from the terminal:
{'Hi': ''}

can anyone please explain what is going on and how to send these two variables?

Answer (score 1):

**[XMLHttpRequest.send(body)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send)** only takes **1** parameter.

You need to post a JSON or send an url-encoded string *(or any other serialized string)*

**JSON**

```
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
xhttp.send(JSON.stringify({ x: x, y: y}));
```

**x-www-form-urlencoded**

```
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhttp.send(`x=${x}&y=${y}`);
```

If you're sending `JSON`, don't forget to add:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
```

Then you will be able to access it this way:

```
const x = req.body.x;
const y = req.body.y;
```

Or using destructuring:

```
const { x, y } = req.body;
```

Comment: I am using bodyParser, but how to access each one of these variable from the server? as req.body is only picking the first variable in xhttp.send(x,y);

Comment: req.body.x; is causing error I dont know why, I have to use req.body only. using this: const { x, y } = req.body; is not getting me right values

Comment: Show your updated code, my code example works fine, you're doing something wrong. Post server & client code.

Comment: client side:  xhttp.send(JSON.stringify({ x: x, y:y}));

Comment: server side: const x = req.body.x;
const y = req.body.y;

Comment: Update your answer, with your **whole** server side code & client side.

Comment: actually I figured out the solution: in server side we should have
var value = req.body;
//to print each value:
console.log(value.x);
console.log(value.y);

Comment: It's the exact same code. You probably have an old `node.js` version that does not support `const`. So my answer is correct :). Just out of curioisity, what `node` version do you have?

Comment: You're running a really old Node.js version, your code is exactly as mine. You should remove your answer, and accept mine.

Comment: what's your node version

Comment: I'm using Node.js 10, which is the current LTS. You should definitely update.